# iOS-style scroll physics with Android-style overscroll indicator

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make my ListView scroll with iOS scroll physics (less friction), for that I can use `BouncingScrollPhysics()`. But I don't want to have the overscroll indicator that comes with it. Instead, I want to have Android 12's stretching overscroll indicator.
Is it possible to change `ClampingScrollPhysics()`'s friction to make it similar to iOS scroll physics? Or alternatively, is it possible to change `BouncingScrollPhysics()`'s overscroll indicator?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the overscroll indicator? BouncingScrollPhysics shouldn't have it by default

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve it, for anyone who is interested:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.cyan),
      scrollBehavior: ScrollBehaviorModified(),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollBehaviorModified extends CupertinoScrollBehavior {
  @override
  ScrollPhysics getScrollPhysics(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollPhysics();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    return StretchingOverscrollIndicator(
      axisDirection: details.direction,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class CustomScrollPhysics extends ClampingScrollPhysics {
  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    final Tolerance tolerance = this.tolerance;
    if (velocity.abs() >= tolerance.velocity || position.outOfRange) {
      return BouncingScrollSimulation(
        spring: spring,
        position: position.pixels,
        velocity: velocity,
        leadingExtent: position.minScrollExtent,
        trailingExtent: position.maxScrollExtent,
        tolerance: tolerance,
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ercan, is there a way to get `StretchingOverscrollIndicator` and `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics` at the same time? I tried tinkering with your solution but no luck.

Comment: @aytunch I haven't tried it, but it should be possible by extending `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics` instead of `ClampingScrollPhysics` in the `CustomScrollPhysics` class